# R: formula, terms and call

Tags: r

I would like to ask if someone knows a good source (e.g. book, blog, notes, slides, ...) which explains formula, terms and call in R on an advanced level for programming. I am struggling with them and have not yet found a comprehensive source.

Thanks and best,

Martin

Comment: At least for calls you may find this one useful: [adv-r](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#calls)

Comment: The R-Inferno  (Patrick Burns (not the hockey coach)) and V. Zoonekynd's manual are good sources.

Comment: Another useful source:   https://developer.r-project.org/model-fitting-functions.html